# autohide rows in excel based on condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have found several responses to similar questions, but I can't make this work for the life of me.  I am trying to automatically hide rows based on an input in a cell.  I have data in columns A thru J, and I want to autohide any rows in which I input a value in column K. I am certain this can be done, but I am at my wit's end trying to get the VBA macros to work!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far, and what exactly failed when you tried that approach.

Comment: @Matt Marshal...I posted an answer below but what Mikegrann is telling you, and granted you're a newbie here, is that you should post the code that you've tried and doesn't work or else its hard for anyone here to assist you.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I tried several items that I found by searching StackOverflow and few others.  None of them seemed to work so I deleted it all and decided to start fresh.

I'll make sure to save what I do from now on so that I can post it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a worksheet change event in your sheet.
Put this code in the code section of your sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 11 Then ' Column K is column number 11
        Target.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

When you change the value in any cell in column k it will hide the entire row.
If you only want it to work in the UsedRange you can edit the code to work that way as well.

Comment: What if the user hits the delete key? Will the row still not hide?

Comment: the OP said he wanted to detect something being input into the cell, not the delete key being pressed.

Comment: @Matt Marshall... if this solution provided you with the answer, please accept it as the solution.

Comment: Go anywhere in Column "K" and hit the delete key, the row will become hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It loops through every cell in column K and hides cells with any text.

```
Sub AutoHideRows()
'Get the last row of the used range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

'Loop through the range looking for non-blank values, and hide those rows
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("K1:K" & LastRow)
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

If your first row of data contains a column header and you want to exclude it from the filter, change this line of code:

```
For Each c In Range("K1:K" & LastRow)
```

to this:

```
For Each c In Range("K2:K" & LastRow)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, 
  Thanks for the response.  I tried this out and nothing happens when I put a value (alpha or numeric) into any cell in column K.

Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Your example could use `specialcells` instead of a loop, `Range("K2:K" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).EntireRow.Hidden = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation on the answer from @dinotom.  It hides the entire row when you enter a value in column K, but not if you delete a value from column K.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 11 And Target.Value <> "" Then ' Column K is column number 11
        Target.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```